# Comments on nominations in an election don't show OP highlighting until after "show more comments" is clicked

Tags: bug, comments, election

I was over looking at the [Mathematics election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) when I noticed that the comments under nominations don't highlight the name of the OP/nominee:

[image]

*Except* when you click "show x more comments", then the highlighting magically appears.

[image]

This is also reproducible on the recent [ServerFault election.](https://serverfault.com/election/4)

Is this a bug? Or is the highlighting purposefully turned off until you show more comments? I think the highlighting is quite useful and would like it better if it showed all the time.

Comment: You also can't upvote comments *ever* on nominations, not sure if this is intended either.

Comment: @hichris123 Yeah that really bothers me as well. I guess that is another feature request/bug?

Comment: @TimStone Yep, you're right.. I even searched :(